# SMTP mail to pickup and send from exchange

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have created a simple mail service with C# that connects to SMTP and sends mail. But connecting to SMTP is very slow method. So I changed delivery settings from Web.config as SpecifiedPickupDirectory.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" >    
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\MyEmails"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSetting>
    ...
</system.net>
```

My application writes email contents as *.eml files to disc.

Is there any way to sending these emails automatically with Exchange Server service.

Comment: Looks like you can import .eml files by calling EmailMessage.Save method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672316(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's simple. Download the Exchange WebService Dll(s) from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35371

Reference the Dll(s) in your projects and send emails using code that's almost exactly like SMTP client.